# Execution stops when checking for unique id

Tags: java, loops

The below code is getting an id from user which is checking if it's unique when I run the program and enter the id  it stops at the line

```
 t.SetID(tuser);
```

does someone know why this is so... at this line it opens the code and highlights the above line

```
 do { 
      String id = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter ticket ID: ");
      int tuser = Integer.parseInt(id);
      t = myAirline.ReturnTicket(tuser);
      if(t == null)
      {
          //number unique
          t.SetID(tuser);
      }
      else{
          JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Duplicate ID: "); 
      }
 }while (t != null);
```

Comment: Please check if there is a breakpoint at this line and application is started in debug mode if you are running in an IDE. Also, which IDE you are using.

Comment: If `t` is `null` what do you expect `t.SetID()` to do?

Comment: Can you add your SetID method?

Comment: Stops means it terminates?

Comment: Can you check if a `NullPointerException` is thrown?